# Intellij IDEA CE 12 Android XML Code Completion not working

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea, code-completion

I just started to learning IntelliJ IDEA CE 12 for Android development, as an alternate to Eclipse.

IDEA is very quick and I'm beginning to like it.
However, when I try to edit Android XML file, the code completion never appears. In my office, I'm using MacBook Air (64bit), and when I tried Mac version, it worked beautifully.
In my home, I'm using Vista (32bit ver) and my laptop specs are not so good. (that's why I choose to change to IDEA from Eclipse...)

I have not changed any Settings after the installation. Is there any option(s) to enable code completion for Android XML editor? Or it is just the matter of machine's performance?

I know it's a rubbish question, but I really need help here.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please check that project is configured properly and your module has [Android facet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/android-facet-page.html) and Android SDK Platform in the dependencies.

IntelliJ IDEA performs indexing of the JSDK, Android Platform and your project when you open it for the first time. You need to wait for the indexing process to complete (progress is displayed in the status bar at the bottom).

Once indexing is complete, you should get all the code completion options available. If for some reason it still doesn't work, try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart IDEA.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Do you mean "Android Designer" & "Android Support" Plugins? If so, I already have both on my module and SDK seems properly set. Actually, code completion for Java file works. But for XML it's not working... I'm at office now and IDEA works perfectly fine on my Mac... I'll try it immediately once I'm back. Also, could you tell me where can I use that command? Thank you again for help!

Comment: Now I'm back at home. I have also done "Invalidate Caches" and restart. Unfortunately, still no luck of code completion for xml. Interestingly though, when I edit Manifest xml file, code completion works! However, when trying to edit layout xml file, code completion never appears...

Comment: Check `idea.log` for exceptions: `Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`

Comment: I don't know why, but when I compiled "MyActivity" for test, suddenly the whole project seems recognised Android SDK and code completion started working! Thanks to smarter and faster code completion, my Android development become faster than ever. Again, Thank you for help! Your tips really helped me understanding this nice IDE!

Comment: Very helpful comment. I don't know what happened but all of a sudden, the auto-completion ceased to work. I did the File | Invalidate Caches and restarted IDEA and it worked. Once it restarts, make sure that you wait till the indexing is complete. You can get the status of index by looking at the status bar. Thanks a ton to @CrazyCoder for sharing such a helpful reply.

Answer (score 1):

Faust,

I was having the same problem and here are the solutions I found:

1. Go to `File->Power Save Mode` and disable it.
2. Go to `File-Settings/Preferences->Editor->Code Completion` and check `Autopopup code completion`
3. Go to `File->Invalidate Caches` and restart.

Disabling Power Save Mode is what fixed it for me!