# IntelliJ: Code completion not working - no suggestion

Tags: html, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use the ctrl + spacebar shortcut in IntelliJ for code completion but every time I do it, it returns "no suggestions".

[image]

This is my project directory, even if I type in starter and then press ctrl-spacebar, there is "no suggestion" even though the file exist in the project directory:

[image]

I have tried the following according to this thread ([Intellij IDEA CE 12 Android XML Code Completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450209/intellij-idea-ce-12-android-xml-code-completion-not-working)):

1. Go to File->Power Save Mode and disable it - it is off.
2. Go to Preferences->Editor->Code Completion and check Autopopup code completion - this has been checked
3. Go to File->Invalidate Caches and restart. - done and no change

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right, there's no obvious problem with the examples and screenshots you've given.  You might be better off contacting IntelliJ IDEA support directly, either opening an issue or using the community forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?intellij-idea

Comment: what Idea version do you use? Is is Ultimate or Community edition?

Comment: Hello. I'm using the community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS/JavaScript completion is supported only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, see the [comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Community Edition provides only basic syntax highlighting for these file types.

Comment: Thank you - I was going crazy pressing ctrl - space on my mac.